# Joomla Exporting Or Downloading Reports To CSV

Tags: excel, csv, joomla, header

I have the following code in my inventory section when i run this code it save an excel file but the result showing the whole html file not my data.

```
<?php

$csv = NULL;
$arr = array("product_name","product_sku","product_in_stock","virtuemart_product_id","product_price_display","product_instock_value");
$csv = "Product Name, Product SKU, In Stock, Booked ordered products, Cost Price, Stock Value \n";
$c=0;
while(list($key,$value)=each($arr)){
$c++;
$cc=1;
foreach ($this->inventorylist as $key => $product){
$cc++;
$csv .= join(',',array($product->product_name.",".$product->product_sku.",".$product->product_in_stock.",".$product->virtuemart_product_id.",".$product->product_price_display.",".$product->product_instock_value))." \n";

}

}

JResponse::clearHeaders();
JResponse::setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', true);
JResponse::setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'csv; filename=inventory_report.csv; size='.strlen($csv), true);
JResponse::sendHeaders();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Khalique

Comment: What happends if you var_dump the `$csv` variable?

Comment: Take a look at the core com_banners component, it downloads a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the brute force solution just to get you going:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

// Echo the csv content.
echo "foo,bar\n1,2";

// Close the application gracefully.
JFactory::getApplication()->close();
```

A slightly cleaner way without using views, but including `&format=raw` in the URL is:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$doc->setMimeEncoding('application/vnd.ms-excel');

$app->setHeader(
    'Content-disposition',
    'attachment; filename="inventory_report.csv"',
    true
);

echo "foo,bar\n1,2";
```

But the best way is to use a download view based on the `raw` document type. You can find an example of this in `com_banners`:

- Controller: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/components/com_banners/controllers/tracks.raw.php
- View: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/components/com_banners/views/tracks/view.raw.php

You might also gain some extra insight from this discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomla-dev-general/dRa_39AGDBY